# Repair holes concrete ceiling (not just masking them)

Tags: concrete, walls, ceiling, hole-repair

An old apartment, where dry wall was a thing yet. The ceiling is concrete, plastered and painted.

There are many holes, from current and previous owners (different light spots installed in different locations).

There is a concern now about just masking these holes with compound and painting. When another person decides to drill new holes to install new lights (or even a projector), it might be too close to an old hole that was masked with compound, and that could cause it to fall. Drilling right by a compound would not give the same grip, and things would fall.

Maybe I wrote too much, but the question is: if masking with compound and paint is not acceptable enough, what would be the way(s) to repair this ceiling so it is like the original, allowing new holes that would be safe as an original ceiling (without the fear of being too close to a masked hole)?

This should be valid for a wall of the same material (not dry wall, that is, a concrete+plaster+paint). Drilling right be a repaired hole with compound might be unsafe if hanging heavy items like a TV.

I know the odds are low, but it can happen if there are many holes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use a resin or hard setting product and make sure the holes are dust free.

Worked well for me, either reusing those holes or having to drill a new hole part through the wall of the repair.

Answer (score 0):

I would add tape over the hole being filled with “mud” all Sheetrock is is paper mud paper the strongest repair you can get is to fill the hole let dry, sand and fill the hole again, put some mud on the surface and a piece of tape larger than the hole. Sand and skim coat. Prime and paint and it will be as strong as any patch can be.

Answer (score 0):

When called upon to fill holes in concrete ceilings when the ceiling fans were being removed, and the lag shields holding it up, I've always used a Sakrete type material but without the stones in it. Make sure the holes are dust free and wet them down a bit. Mix up your cement a little thicker than normal and start packing it into the holes. Have a dowel rod a little smaller than the hole and use it to pack in the cement and get rid of air bubbles. When the filled holes are flush with the rest of the ceiling, put some masking or duct tape over the hole to secure it until the cement hardens.